# Need help echo not show any result

Tags: php, html

Hi all php expert i want to know the reason if i user the following line of code

`echo '<text';`

`echo "<text";`

above line of code will result blank.

Can any php expert could face that issue. Need reason

Comment: use echo htmlspecialchars("<text", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); to display

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are echoing start of HTML tags (like `<div class="a"`). No error will ever be thrown by HTML. Replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` to break HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Write like this

```
echo '&lt; text';
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Its working :**

```
<?php
echo '&lt; text';
?>
```

If you write **<** in echo statement after the **'** or **"** behaves as a HTML tag.HTML tag not displayed to the user that's why it always result you blank.

Comment: In php `echo "<text";` will echo no special character (print in on command line and it will be fine). But since any output is parsed as HTML, than `<text` becomes tag of HTML and tags are not displayed for user.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to output plain text, place the following in the beginning of your script

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
```

After that you will see symbols just fine.

Answer (score 0):

PHP echoing **<** as open html tag if it follows by letters.
So just add a space after **<**

```
<?php
echo '< text';
?>
```

you can use > as you like